# Apply method on directive instance

Tags: angular, angular6

in Angular 6 I got a multiple elements that use a drag-scroll directive.

Everything works fine but I want to add buttons that will scroll given instance not all of them :)

How to address moveLeft() and  moveRight() fn to the specific directive instance? I was trying to use @ViewChildren but this access all of the instances in forEach.

The number of the rows that will use scroll will be dynamic so I did not wanted to give them any id's.

```
  <!-- FIRST ROW -->
         <div class="dragscroll" dragScroll scrollbar-hidden="true" 
 drag-scroll-y-disabled="true">
             <div>
               <img src="/freeze_frame_image_692.png"> 
               <img src="/freeze_frame_image_692.png"> 
               <img src="/freeze_frame_image_692.png"> 
             </div>
             <div>
                <button class="prev-exercise"(click)="moveLeft($event)">Prev</button>
                 <button class="next-exercise" (click)="moveRight($event)">Next</button>
             </div>
         </div>

  <!-- Second ROW -->
         <div class="dragscroll" dragScroll scrollbar-hidden="true" drag-scroll-y-disabled="true">
             <div>
               <img src="/freeze_frame_image_692.png"> 
               <img src="/freeze_frame_image_692.png"> 
               <img src="/freeze_frame_image_692.png"> 
             </div>
             <div>
                <button class="prev-exercise"(click)="moveLeft($event)">Prev</button>
                 <button class="next-exercise" (click)="moveRight($event)">Next</button>
             </div>
         </div>

  <!-- Third ROW -->
         <div class="dragscroll" dragScroll scrollbar-hidden="true" drag-scroll-y-disabled="true">
             <div>
               <img src="/freeze_frame_image_692.png"> 
               <img src="/freeze_frame_image_692.png"> 
                <img src="/freeze_frame_image_692.png"> 
             </div>
             <div>
                <button class="prev-exercise"(click)="moveLeft($event)">Prev</button>
                <button class="next-exercise" (click)="moveRight($event)">Next</button>
             </div>
         </div>
```

And here we got ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChildren, Input, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { DragScrollModule, DragScrollDirective } from 'ngx-drag-scroll';
@Component({
  selector: 'program-list',
  templateUrl: './program-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./program-list.component.scss']
})

export class ProgramListComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  programs: any;


  @ViewChildren(DragScrollDirective) ds: QueryList<DragScrollDirective>;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ds.forEach((dragel) => {
    dragel.scrollbarHidden = true;
    });
  }
  moveLeft(event) {
    this.ds.forEach((dragel) => {
      dragel.moveLeft();
    });
  }

  moveRight() {
    this.ds.forEach((dragel) => {
    dragel.moveRight();
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Add code for DragScrollDirective class.

Comment: I use this one - https://github.com/bfwg/ngx-drag-scroll .

Comment: You will have to make changes in directive class for this. You can download this class from github, and then add these functions in its directive class.